# iOS Embedded Framework with Embedded Framework

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, code-signing, codesign

I'm working on a framework which embeds another framework (from CocoaPods) for error logging on iOS. This is working very well, and I can embed such a framework in an iOS application for testing, codesign everything, and debug on my own device easily. Unfortunately, when attempting to upload such an application to Apple for distribution, I get an error message as such:

> Invalid Bundle. The bundle at '<myapp>.app/Frameworks/<myframework>.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90206 for id ***

I'm not sure if this message indicates that I'm not allowed to embed a framework in another framework or what. It seems the automatic codesigning Xcode is doing is not recursing to the deepest embedded framework upload (I have a script to manually sign everything on build). Does anyone have experience with an error like this or know where to look? It seems others have asked questions about embedding frameworks in other frameworks before, but most of these are how to get linking to work or how to properly reference these nested frameworks. My issue is specifically if I am allowed to upload such things to test flight/the app store, and how to do so if it is possible. Most people having this issue seem to have disabled swift support, but none of the projects I'm using have swift code.

Answer (score 0):

Nested bundle cannot include a framework. You can check this [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle?language=objc).

> iOS and tvOS support frameworks and Swift system libraries at the topmost app level; a nested bundle, like an app extension, can’t include a framework.

And there is a warning block that worth being noticed:

> If you put content in the wrong location, you may encounter hard-to-debug code signing and distribution problems. These problems aren’t always immediately obvious. For example, when building a Mac app, incorrectly placed code might work during day-to-day development, but might cause problems during notarization.

So that is the reason everything seems normal while running in debug mode but failed at distribution.